# Rust returning multiple errors

Tags: rust

I am learning `Rust` and I would like to know what is the idiomatic way of writing a function that could run into multiple error types. For instance, in the function `get_account_with_creds` I am trying to return a struct `AccountForResponse` if the credentials match. The function could possibly run into a database error, so the `Result` could be a `PoolError`. I am using `unwrap` a few places because the error types are different. How can I improve this? I am also not sure about returning `Ok(None)`

```
pub async fn get_account_with_creds(db: &Db, creds: AccountForLogin) -> Result<Option<AccountForResponse>, PoolError> {
    let client: Client = db.get().await?;
    let stmt = client
        .prepare("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, password from accounts WHERE email = $1")
        .await?;
    let rows = client.query(&stmt, &[&creds.email]).await?;
    let row = rows.first().unwrap();
    let hashed_password: &str = row.get(4);
    match bcrypt::verify(creds.password, hashed_password).unwrap() {
        false => Ok(None),
        true => {
            let account = Some(AccountForResponse {
                id: Some(row.get(0)),
                first_name: row.get(1),
                last_name: row.get(2),
                email: row.get(3),
            });
            Ok(account)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [anyhow crate](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it is exactly what I am looking for. But is using `anyhow` the idiomatic way of handling returning multiple error types in Rust? I intend to use it everywhere I face this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you expect to *handle* the errors (to recover from them in a way that is specific to which error occurred), or if you're writing a library, then define an `enum` type which can hold any of the errors might occur. Each enum variant might either contain the original error value (so it can be retrieved), or not (if the original error is purely an implementation detail). The `thiserror` crate can help you implement `Error` and `From` for such enums.

  ```rust
  #[derive(thiserror::Error)]
  enum LoginError {
      Database(#[from] PoolError),
      AccountNotFoundOrIncorrectPassword,  // Use this in place of your unwraps
  }
  ```
- If you simply want to collect the errors and report/log them, without the *code* worrying about the differences between different errors (because you don't have a specific plan beyond "log it and/or abort"), then you can use `anyhow`, or stick to the standard library and use `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` — there are provided `From`/`Into` conversions for it so that the `?` operator can turn any error that implements `std::error::Error` into the boxed form.